# Embed a fillable pdf form on web page

Tags: html, pdf, embedding

Is there anyway to embed a fillable pdf form on a web page that the viewer would be able to fill out and send with the Adobe submit function?  without having to click through or download the actual pdf

thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Adobe Reader will display a PDF in Protected Mode when it's viewed in a browser, for security reasons it's basically not interactive. Users can add your domain to a trusted host and then the PDF becomes interactive.

However, you can't really count on the PDF being opened in an Adobe viewer (Reader or Acrobat) when it's opened in a browser even when an Adobe viewer is installed on the machine and set as the default handler for that file type. The most common browsers have PDF viewers built in that just don't function in the same way as their Adobe counterparts.

You're really much better off linking to the PDF form in a way that forces the PDF to download (through .htaccess or something) and open in the default handler.

Comment: thanks @joelgeraci. Would it be possible to create a button to download a fillable pdf automatically once the button is clicked so than the viewer can fill the form out themselves and email it with the adobe submit function? I know I can do this with a regular pdf.. but a fillable pdf? im worried that the form won't look the same to the customer

Comment: Yes just create a link to the PDF but store the PDF on your server in a folder where files can only be downloaded. I use a .htaccess file with one line "Header set Content-Disposition "attachment". Then your user will just be prompted to download the file when they click on a normal link to the PDF. Be sure that the submit button on the PDF uses a fully qualified URL though.

Comment: Thanks again @joelgeraci, I will give this a try. Just to be clear would this be considered at qualified URL ? http://advantecglobal.com/images/ProductSpecSheet.pdf

Comment: Sorry. The fully qualified URL must be to the server script, not the PDF. It'd start with http:// and go on to the script itself.